# System of 3 differential equations that i failed to solve. May someone halp me to solve it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image: Math problem. I find eigenvalues]

I do not know what to do next.

Please explain me how to solve it .

[image: I find eigenvectors and Jordan matrix]

Comment: More carefully written  $$x' = 4x + 6y -2z +t \\ y' = -2 x - 3y +z - t^2 \\ z' = 2x + 3y - z + 2$$

Comment: `Solve[{4*L^2 + 16*L - L^3 - 4*L^2 - 16== 0}, {L}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DSolve` to solve your system directly.

```
Eq1 = x'[t] == 4*x[t] + 6*y[t] - 2*z[t] + t
Eq2 = y'[t] == -2*x[t] - 3*y[t] + z[t] - t^2
Eq3 = z'[t] == 2*x[t] + 3*y[t] - z[t] + 2
DSolve[{Eq1, Eq2, Eq3}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t}]
```

And if you just want to find the eigenvalues then you can use `Solve`

```
Solve[{4*L^2 + 16*L - L^3 - 4*L^2 - 16 == 0}, {L}]
```

Here $L$stands for $\lambda$.

Comment: I need to solve this system of differential-equation using Jordan matrix